# Where should the continuing operator be placed for long equations?

Tags: multline

In mathematical writing, for long equations (using multline environment), where should the continuing operator, such as +,-, /, etc., be placed: at the end of first line or before the start of the next line? I have shown the two types in the attached image. [image]

Which of the two is the 'professional' way, or does it depend on the journal style? Also, do these equations need ellipsis somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: Usually the letter is preferred as the + can be overlooked in the first example. Exceptions can be made if space is a problem. Note also a tradition usually seen in eastern europe where the + is repeated (aka the combination of both). This is not normally seen in Western typographic tradition.

Comment: if you do use the first form you need `{}` at the end so you get an infix +, but normally you break after the + in _inline_ math but _before_ the + in display, or as daleif comments the Russian (and perhaps other  Eastern European) tradition duplicates the +.